# How to compare password when using bcrypt nest js log in api in mysql

Tags: mysql, nestjs, mean, mern, nestjs-config

How I can compare password when signin in using bcrypt,I am facing problem at the time of signin for comparing password.From that select query i can get the matched mailid but how to get hash password?????????????????

note:I am not using typeorm...

Here is my service.ts code,

```
    import { ConflictException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SignInDto,SignUpDto } from '../dto';
import { execute } from '../mysql';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { FORMERR } from 'dns';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    // ------SignUp-------

  public async CREATE(Dto: SignUpDto): Promise<any> {
    const [account]:any = await execute(
      `
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM  
            account 
        WHERE 
            email = ? AND 
            is_active = ? AND  
            is_deleted = ?  
            `,
      [Dto.email.toLowerCase(), 1, 0],
    );

    if (account) {
      throw new ConflictException('Account already exists on this email id.');
    }

    Dto.email = Dto.email.toLowerCase();
    Dto.password = await bcrypt.hash(Dto.password, 12);
    Dto.confirmPassword = await bcrypt.hash(Dto.confirmPassword, 12);

    const data = { ...Dto};

    return await execute(`INSERT INTO account SET ?`, [data]);
}

// -------SignIn---------

public async GET(Dto: SignInDto): Promise<any> {
    const [isExist]:any = await execute(
      `
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            account 
        WHERE 
            email = ? AND 
            is_active = ? AND 
            is_deleted = ?
        `,
      [Dto.email.toLowerCase(), 1, 0],
    );

   

*if (!isExist) {
        const compare=await bcrypt.compare()
      throw new ConflictException('Account does not exists.');
    }*

    return {
      id: isExist.id,
    };
  }
}
```

conroller.ts

```
    import { Controller, Post, Body, HttpCode, HttpStatus, Res, Get, ParseIntPipe, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiOperation, ApiResponse, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { SignUpDto, SignInDto } from '../dto';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private readonly _authService: AuthService) { }

    @Post('/sign-up')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiResponse({ status: HttpStatus.OK, description: 'Success' })
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'SignUp' })
    public async SIGNUP(@Res() res: Response, @Body() Dto: SignUpDto): Promise<any> {
        const result: any = await this._authService.CREATE(Dto);
        if (result) {
            return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ status: HttpStatus.OK, message: `Registration completed successfully.` });
        }
        return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, message: `Something went wrong. Please try again later.` });
    }

    @Post('/sign-in')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiResponse({ status: HttpStatus.OK, description: 'Success.' })
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'SignIn' })
    public async SIGNIN(@Res() res: Response, @Body() Dto: SignInDto): Promise<any> {
        const result: any = await this._authService.GET(Dto);
        if (result) {
            res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ status: HttpStatus.OK, data: result, message: `Successfull` });
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing problem at the time of signin for comparing password.From that select query i can get the matched mailid but how to get hash password?????????????????

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's no need to save the hashed confirmation password. The confirmation password should just be checked that it matches the password, to make sure the user sent in the password they expected to.

Second, assuming you have a `password` column, you should be able to get the password via `isExist.password`. Then you can check if the passwords are the same using bcrypt via `bcrypt.compare(Dto.password, isExist.password)`. Bcrypt will take care of computing the same salt based on the hashed password (it's part of the hash actually). The `compare` method will return a boolean if the passed password hashes to the same hashed value and you can tell then if it was correct or not.

Comment: Yes,I got your answer and it worked....